# What does "myjsFunc" represent?

Tags: jquery

For instance, 
    `<href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>`

I want to link the `onclick` command to the `.click` function. How do I do this? I tried `onclick ="click()"` , `onclick ="click(function()"`, both don't work.

HTML:

```
 <area shape="rect" coords="710,44,866,84"  href="javascript:void(0)"   id="se" >
```

My jQuery: (updated per cdoeparadox's )

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#numb1').hide().delay(800).fadeIn('normal');

});

$('.se').click(function(){
$('#SF').show();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

#### At present

- `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>` means that, when you `click` on this anchor tag it will call function `myJsFunc()` and
- `javascript:void(0)` stop the default page load to click on that anchor tag.

---

#### What can you do

You need to use `class` or `id` attribute to point out the corresponding `<a>`. For example:

***HTML***

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="someclick">Link</a>
```

***jQuery***

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#numb1').hide().delay(800).fadeIn('normal');

    $('area').click(function() {
        $('#SF').show();

    });

    $('a.someclick').click(function() {
        // do something
    });
});​
```

---

#### Note

Put all of your code within `$(document).ready({ .. })`.

Comment: Thanks for editing my jquery =) But the link still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `id` attribute to the exact `<a>` that you want enabled, like this:

```
<a id="example_id">Some text</a>
```

Then you can add the following:

```
$('#example_id').click(function(){
    // Place the code here
});
```

Remember to replace 'example_id' with something that makes sense in your case.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the onclick ="xxx" from the html. The jquery

```
$('your-id').click(function(){
})
```

will handle the click event